# Android Studio 2022 Gradle Problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

it's been 3 days I'm struggling with this problem and didn't find a single solution to this.

Everything was good I had many projects in android studio 2022 working well but suddenly it seems all of my Gradle files are changed ?! or they are just I don't know what happened to them they are broken! every single project I open even the new project gives me an error in every single dependency or plugin ill share the information about it below here:

Every single Build.Gradle (Project) File :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Sample build.Gradle (App)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teach.mytest"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

** Sample gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-rc-1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

** Sample settings.gradle: **

```
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyTest"
include ':app'
```

**Errors:**
simple explaining about errors The errors are simply coming for all the projects are the same but when one project has extra dependency it gets errors like the below too for that dependency
also when I change the Gradle version from properties it's downloading the new Gradle working well but in the build phase it gives the same errors

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

```
Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
```

```
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.2')
Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

** Whatever i did ?**

- I tried to create a new project
- I tried to change the java version
- I tried to change the Gradle version and the application version
- I tried to invalidate caches and restart

** Notes **
I'm using Java 15 mainly in my projects default android studio java version is 11
I change it via setting > build tool
But the problem is same also same in kotlin projects

**Edit:**
I changed the android.application version to 7.0.0
everything downloaded started from scratch at the final part its giving only error for gradle version 7.0.0

Comment: Are the Gradle code blocks you added are correct? I mean exactly how it appeared on your Android Studio? Since I saw this line `options common to all sub-projects/modules.` and it is not commented out.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez
Ye it was mistake i just edited that its already commented

Comment: Thanks, it is confusing with all these samples. Are the samples yours?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly all of the problems was related to country network restrictions you can fix that by adding other repositories to gradle

personally changing repos to a clone repo named aliyun was solution

for example adding this to your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/apache-snapshots' }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/apache-snapshots' }
}
}
```